# Espresso test failing with progress dialog not removed from top

Tags: android, android-espresso

I am writing Espresso tests for my app. One of my tests is getting failed when I run it, when it's debugged it just works fine. It appears to be a threading issue. When calling an api, code first shows ProgressDialog which is removed when response is received. Test failure indicates that progress dialog was still shown when this test is run.

**Test is:**

```
@Rule
    public IntentsTestRule<ScrDoctorHomeNew> activityTestRule = new IntentsTestRule<>(ScrDoctorHomeNew.class,false,false);

@Test
    public void testRecommendationCountIOException() {
        ApiFactory.INSTANCE.setErrorObservable(Observable.error(new IOException("Network Error")));

        activityTestRule.launchActivity(null);

        onView(withId(R.id.lblOldRecommandation)).check(matches(withText(String.format(activityTestRule.getActivity().getString(R.string.txt_doctor_old_recommandation), 0))));
    }
```

**Fragment showing progressDialog**

```
private void fetchProfileData() {
        if (mActivity != null) {
            mActivity.showProgressDialogInUiThread(mActivity.getResources().getString(R.string.str_loading));
        }
        ApiFactory.INSTANCE.getDocProfileRetriever().getProfile(LocalDataManager.getInstance().getUser().getUserId()).subscribe(
                new Subscriber<ProfileMessage>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onCompleted() {
                        if (mActivity != null) {
                            mActivity.dismissProgressDialogInUiThread();
                        }
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(Throwable e) {
                        if (mActivity != null) {
                            mActivity.dismissProgressDialogInUiThread();
                        }
                        updateRecommendationCount(0);
                        Log.e(HomeFragment.class.getSimpleName(),"Exception:",e);
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onNext(ProfileMessage profileMessage) {
                        if (profileMessage != null) {
                            ArrayList<String> list = profileMessage.getProblemRecommendations();
                            if (list != null) {
                                updateRecommendationCount(list.size());
                            } else {
                                updateRecommendationCount(0);
                            }
                        } else {
                            updateRecommendationCount(0);
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

**BaseActivity showing progress dialog**

```
public void showProgressDialogInUiThread(String text) {
        mProgressDlgFragment =
                ProgressDialogFragment.getInstance(false, false, text,
                        R.style.ProgressDialogStyle);
        mProgressDlgFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), ProgressDialogFragment.DIALOG_TAG);

    }

    public void dismissProgressDialogInUiThread() {
        if (mProgressDlgFragment != null) {
            mProgressDlgFragment.dismiss();
        }
    }
```

**Error shown is:**

> android.support.test.espresso.NoMatchingViewException: No views in hierarchy found matching: with id: tk.swapnilUtilities.eRecommendationAndroid:id/lblOldRecommandation
>
> View Hierarchy:
>       +>DecorView{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=480, height=854, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
>       |
>       +->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=480, height=854, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
>       |
>       +-->ViewStub{id=16909149, visibility=GONE, width=0, height=0, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=true, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
>       |
>       +-->FrameLayout{id=16908290, res-name=content, visibility=VISIBLE, width=480, height=816, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=38.0, child-count=1}
>       |
>       +--->RelativeLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=480, height=816, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0, child-count=1}
>       |
>       +---->LinearLayout{id=-1, visibility=VISIBLE, width=480, height=187, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=314.0, child-count=2}
>       |
>       +----->CustomProgressIndicator{id=2131558672, res-name=progress_indicator, visibility=VISIBLE, width=114, height=114, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=183.0, y=0.0, child-count=2}
>       |
>       +------>ImageView{id=2131558674, res-name=progress_indicator_view_inner, visibility=VISIBLE, width=114, height=114, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
>       |
>       +------>ImageView{id=2131558675, res-name=progress_indicator_view_outer, visibility=VISIBLE, width=114, height=114, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=0.0, y=0.0}
>       |
>       +----->TextView{id=2131558673, res-name=tv_message, visibility=VISIBLE, width=129, height=49, has-focus=false, has-focusable=false, has-window-focus=true, is-clickable=false, is-enabled=true, is-focused=false, is-focusable=false, is-layout-requested=false, is-selected=false, root-is-layout-requested=false, has-input-connection=false, x=175.0, y=138.0, text=Loading, input-type=0, ime-target=false, has-links=false}
>       |
>       at dalvik.system.VMStack.getThreadStackTrace(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.Thread.getStackTrace(Thread.java:579)
>       at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:92)
>       at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:56)
>       at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.runSynchronouslyOnUiThread(ViewInteraction.java:184)
>       at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.check(ViewInteraction.java:158)
>       at tk.swapnilUtilities.eRecommendationAndroid.ui.ScrHomeNewTest.testRecommendationCountIOException(ScrHomeNewTest.java:59)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
>       at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
>       at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
>       at android.support.test.internal.statement.UiThreadStatement.evaluate(UiThreadStatement.java:55)
>       at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:270)
>       at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
>       at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
>       at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
>       at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
>       at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
>       at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:59)
>       at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:262)
>       at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1667)

**[EDIT]** I have disabled the animation but the results still the same. I am using mock mode to simulate response received. Mock error response is returned immediately. After running the app manually I observed that progress dialog is not removed until my app is sent to background.

Can someone point me how can I fix this bug?

Answer (score 0):

There's at least a couple of things that it could be.

1. Make sure you disable animations before running the test. You may have done this but it's not clear and worth pointing out for other readers.

> "To avoid flakiness, we highly recommend that you turn off system
>   animations on the virtual or physical device(s) used for testing.
>
> On your device, under Settings->Developer options disable the
>   following 3 settings: Window animation scale Transition animation
>   scale Animator duration scale"

https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/setup/

---

2. The other thing, and which may well be the problem, is that the test is finishing before the response was received. Which makes sense if the progress bar is still there. The solution is to use an Espresso IdlingResource.

> "The centerpiece of Espresso is its ability to seamlessly synchronize
>   all test operations with the application being tested. By default,
>   Espresso waits for UI events in the current message queue to be
>   handled and for default AsyncTasks to complete before it moves on to
>   the next test operation.
>
> However, there are instances where applications perform background
>   operations (such as communicating with web services) via non-standard
>   means; for example: direct creation and management of threads.
>
> In such cases, you have to use Idling Resources to inform Espresso of
>   the app’s long-running operations."

https://google.github.io/android-testing-support-library/docs/espresso/idling-resource/index.html

---

**If the documentation isn't clear enough - or alternatively, check out the codelab** https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/android-testing

There are several examples of how to use the Idling resource. There's a few pieces to it so I would recommend taking a look to save yourself some time. At least look at the source code if nothing else.

Comment: I have disabled the animation but the results still the same. I am using mock mode to simulate response received. Mock error response is returned immediately.

Comment: Have you tried using "descendentOf" just before the withId part? I don't know what the layout looks like but sometimes that can help.